# How can I make timeout = 1 second for wait_event_timeout function?

Tags: c, timeout, linux-kernel, time-wait

How can I make timeout = 1 second for wait_event_timeout  function? 
Function : `wait_event_timeout (wq,condition,timeout);`

How can I make timeout = 1 second.

And if call function like that :  `wait_event_timeout(queue,flag!='n',30*HZ);`

timeout =???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function wait_event_timeout takes its timeout value in jiffies. Use the constant `HZ` (number of timer ticks per second) to specify time in jiffies.  The expression `HZ` is the equivalent of one second.  The expression `30 * HZ` is the equivalent of 30 seconds.

```
wait_event_timeout (wq,condition,HZ);
```

Answer (score 4):

[wait_event_timeout](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/device-drivers/API-wait-event-timeout.html) take timeout in jiffies. and `HZ` is a defined identifier in linux which means 1 second. So `n * HZ` means `n` seconds. Hope now you can convert jiffies time to real world time, like `n millisecond = n*HZ/1000`

Answer (score 0):

just a remark: take into account that HZ differs from system to system. on most systems / kernels i know Hz is set to 100. so dividing it by 1000 to get milliseconds will always end up with value 0.